# Microsoft Project Does Not Sum The Work Total Of Resources Other Than The First Resource In The List

Tags: resource-planning, resources

On the Default Resource Usage view, totals are displayed only for the first resource. Others are not added and displayed.
[image: Resource Usage sheet shows correct total for first resource. Other resources the total is zero]

The zero total is also present in other reports. How can this be fixed?

Comment: You might want to add a tag and/or edit the comment to add the name of the tool you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Julie,
Yes you should see the totals for each resource. I suggest you do the following. Save your project file as XML. Then re-open the XML file in Project. Note, you will lose any custom formatting.

You should also check to insure that you have the latest updates for Project.